# how can I restrict to user to select only a specific time range in datetimepicker windows c#

Tags: c#-4.0

how can I restrict to user to select only  a specific  **time range** in "datetimepicker" control  windows c#.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Set the MinDate and MaxDate.

```
   dtPicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(2000, 6, 20);
   dtPicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
```